# Does `npm install` retrieve binaries or sources?

Tags: binary-code, debian, package-manager, npm

I am starting to use `npm install` a lot for development, but I fear about its security consequences. Does `npm install` retrieve binaries or sources?

If it's binaries, it's already a deal breaker for me.

If it's sources, what level of scrutiny is the node.js community having over the package repository? (E.g. I would like to compare this repository to other repositories, such as debian package repositories, which I guess are the safest out there.)

Comment: What's the difference between binaries and sources when you run JavaScript in node.js?

Comment: Rory McCune, did a [good talk](https://prezi.com/vjjq6n2x72ko/security-and-modern-software-deployment-owasp-edition/) about this. He's pretty active on this site, so you may hear from him directly.

Comment: pretty ironic that the link to that security talk requires Flash ;)